# switch light from motion detection to using the dedicated switch to turn lights on and off

Tags: electrical

I want to change my motion detector on my light to using just the dedicated on/off switch that works the electric for them.

Comment: So, you want to not use the motion detector feature any more and just have a regular light controlled by a switch?

Comment: Read the instruction of your motion detector. I think a quick flip on the switch will override the auto sensing function.

Comment: What make and model is this motion detector light?

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing the motion detector in most cases requires that you change the wiring in the junction box behind the detector.

Based on north american colour codes, in the junction box, disconnect the black that goes to the detector and instead connect it to the red that goes to the lights. You'll need to cut the power to the circuit in question.

This assumes the detector is wired via a on/off switch elsewhere (e.g. indoors) which controls whether it is off.

Alternatively you can get a detector that has a permanently on function, either by an override switch at the detector, or by means of a special *on -> off (10 seconds) -> on* sequencing that puts it in permanent on mode until the next sunrise.

If you don't know what all this means, ask a friend who is familiar with electric work to do this for you.